# "Questions that may already have your answer" ignores tags?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

The list of "questions that may already have your answer" that appears when asking a question seems to ignore tags, as far as I can tell, even if you enter them down below.

If I am right about this, this decreases the effectiveness of this feature, because the list is likely to be populated with questions in some other programming language etc.

If we do want to take tags into account in this search, then it would make sense to move the tags entry area up to the top, as I seem to recall someone proposed doing recently.